# Prestashop any input I add is encrypted

Tags: php, prestashop

I have added a `<input name=whatever type=hidden>` in `authentication.tpl` in register form so I have some stats(won't get in details)

I read that hidden POST in  `AuthController.php` and then insert it in the database.

Problem is that the value always comes up encoded , something like this:

```
b40c094ed9549ae0bd311122b034a15c
```

I tried reading that POST the normal way + `trim(Tools::getValue('whatever'));`
 but the result is the same.

Anyone could help me? Thank you!

Comment: no answers but downvoted , amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a name to your input, then get by his name.

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_input" value="b40c094ed9549ae0bd311122b034a15c">
```

and in php side :

```
trim(Tools::getValue('my_input'));
```

if the value is not the good one, try simply with $_POST, try also urldecode, because some input are encoded( like the input named "back"):

```
urldecode(trim(Tools::getValue('my_input')));
```